# install python pymssql package without pip / proxy

Tags: python, pip, tar, offline, pymssql

I have a python script that leverages pymssql and currently this is running on my DEV Server. I need to deploy this to PRO however and I do not want to setup a proxy on my linux server. it has Python 2.7 installed but no pip.

Can i somehow take the pymssql package from the current working dev env and tar it up, move it across to the PRO server.

Comment: Why not download the tar file from pypi.org directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/#files) a wheel for your platform, rename it to `*.zip`, extract the zip, transfer to the server files `_mssql.so` and `pymssql.so`, move these files to `site-packages` directory in Python.